# Emacs imenu integration with cedet code auto-completion

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, menu, cedet

Hi I can't integrate the imenu with the CEDET code completion. what appears when I invoke auto-completion is another buffer with the possible words.

[reference](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html)

My .emacs file:

```
(require 'color-theme)
    (color-theme-initialize)
    (color-theme-blue-mood)

;; Load CEDET
(load-file "/home/user/cedet-1/common/cedet.el")
(global-ede-mode 1)                      ; Enable the Project management system
(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers)      ; Enable prototype help and smart completion 
(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)            ; Enable template insertion menu

;; control + space
(global-set-key [?\C- ] 'semantic-complete-analyze-inline)

(load-library "completion")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'complete)

(defun my-semantic-hook ()
  (imenu-add-to-menubar "TAGS"))
(add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'my-semantic-hook)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but I'll guess that when you select `C-SPC`, you expect a menu to pop up?  The code completion engine uses a bunch of different completion output mechanisms, but a menu isn't one of them because the Emacs menu system grabs focus, and prevents further typing.  If you just want a menu, then you should bind `C-SPC` to `semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu` instead.

Imenu is a tool that shows all tags in a buffer in a menu.  Completion is a system by which Emacs provides a list of possible words that will complete some symbol.  They are not related with the sole exception of when Imenu's tag collection mechanism is used by by a completion prompt, which CEDET does not enable.